# Accessing static form from GUIbuilder via code

Tags: java, forms, codenameone

I am a total newbie with Codename One and have been studying up by watching the various tutorials etc. But there is a basic concept that I just can't seem to grasp.

When I design a form in the GUIBuilder, how do I reference the form from my code?

I.e. I designed my form in the UI Builder. Now in my main source code, I would like to add a toolbar to the form. Inside the GUIBuilder the form is called "Main", but statements such as `Main.show()`, `Main.hide()` etc do not work.

I managed to get the form "imported" for lack of a better word by using

```
private Form home;
...
...
home=Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
...

home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(edit);
```

Which works, but surely there must be a way of accessing the form directly without having to get the currently active instance? i.e. Something like 
`Main.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(edit);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `beforeShow()` and `postShow()` of your form and just reference the parameter which represents the form.

To add commands, it's advisable that you do that in the `beforeShow()` method and long process like remote data fetching should be done in `postShow()`.

For instance, let's say your form name is `Main` and was created in GUI Builder, you can do the following:

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(final Form f) {
    f.removeAllCommands();

    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
    f.setToolbar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleComponent(new Label("My Form Name", "Title"));
    toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(edit);
    toolbar.addCommandToRightBar(backCommand);
    f.setBackCommand(backCommand);

    ...
}

@Override
protected void postMain(final Form f) {
    //fetch remote data here

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Diamond, just to make sure, I understand 100%, the code for the GUIForm is in StateMachineBase.java file. My main source-code from where I would like to interact with the form is in SecureCom.java (The main Java file for my project), so using your approach, I can assign the statically created form to a form identifier such as 

private Form home;

protected void postMain(final Form f) {
   home = f;
}

And then interact with the form from my primary code with main.WHATEVER functions I wish to access ?

Comment: This should be done in `StateMachine.java`, don't touch the `StateMachineBase.java`. the `beforeShow()` and `postShow()` could be generated automatically for you by selecting your form in GUI Builder and switch to `Events` tab, then click the applicable button.